# Azure WebApp - System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation not showing anywhere

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

I have an Azure WebApp, it has both Application Logging (Filesystem) and (Blob) enabled. I retrieve some data both in blob and Log Stream, but this seems to be some automated data (incoming requests, SQL queries, lifecycle events, etc) but I don't see my `System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation` calls anywhere.

When I run the app locally I see these logs in output window, but not on Azure.

Is there some setting that I'm missing?

[image: azure portal screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In a asp.net core web app, we use the `ILogger` for the logging. More details are [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/26/asp-net-core-logging/).

Your settings in the azure portal is ok, just add some code in your project, sample as below:

In the Startup.cs -> Configure method, the method looks like below(Use ILoggerFactory here):

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory logger)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

           //add the following two lines of code
           logger.AddConsole();
           logger.AddDebug();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Then in the controller.cs:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public HomeController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<HomeController>();
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";
            //Trace.TraceInformation("TraceInformation ---this is from contact page.....");
            _logger.LogInformation("ILogger --- this is from contact page!!!!");
            return View();
        }

       //other code
}
```

After publish to azure, the logs logged by ILogger can be seen in Log Stream and blob:

[image]